# Trouble adding string to LinkedList in C

Tags: c, string, struct, linked-list, c-strings

I want to add a string to a linked list in C. I was able to  figure out how to add a integer, so I thought adding a string wouldn't be much different. So I tried the following:

```
struct node{
   char val;
   struct node * next;
};

typedef struct node item;

void linked_list(char letter[]) {
    item * curr, * head;
    int i;

    head = NULL;

    curr = (item *)malloc(sizeof(item));
    curr->val = letter;
    curr->next  = head;
    head = curr;     

    curr = head;

    while(curr) {
        printf("%s\n", curr->val);
        curr = curr->next ;
    }
}
```

However, I keep getting an

> assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

warning and

> format '%s' expects type 'char *', but argument 2 has 'int'

If, in the struct, val is a character, why am I getting this error?

Side note: `char letter[]` is passing in letters/characters from a separate main method.

I am learning about C and linked lists from this tutorial:http://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists.

Comment: the struct defines a `char` not a `char[]` or `char*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

val is a `char`, which is actually a number between 0 - 255.

What you want is a `char *`, which is a string.